# how to disable autoclosing of tags in jquery

Tags: jquery, tags

I want to break my `<ul>` into multiple `<ul>` tags, I have 10 `<li>` in my `<ul>` and I want to break into 2 `<ul>` (5 `<li>` each). To do the same, I am taking 5th `<li>` and appending `</ul><ul>` using $(this).after().

But Jquery automatically reverse the text and auto close the `<ul>`.

Any Idea how to disable to auto close?

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to disable auto close. What you want is to add a *new* `UL` after the first one, and then add to that one, the last five `LI`s of the first list. To get a reference to the `LI`s following the first five, you can do:

```
$('myFirstUL li:gt(4)');
```

*gt* being *greater than* zero-based index.

Full code example: http://jsbin.com/ofowe/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot, I took those li and put in different ul

Answer (score 3):

While David's solution is an elegant one for the specific problem, another possibility for the general auto-closing tags problem would be to not use `.append` at all. Use a variable instead, and use `.html(my_variable)` at the end. I came across this while trying to do nested UL lists for this very simple Table Of Content thing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var prev='';
  var toc = '';
  $("h2, h3, h4, h5").each(function(i) {
    var h = $(this);
    var level = h.attr("tagName");
    if (level != prev) {
      if (prev == '') {
        toc += "<ul>\n";
      }
      else {
        if (level < prev) {
          toc += "</ul>\n";
        }
        else {
          toc += "<ul>\n";
        }
      }
      prev = level;
    }
    toc += '<li><a href="#' + h.attr('id') + '">' + h.html() + "</a></li>\n";
  });
  toc += '</ul>';
  $("#toc").html(toc);
});
```

Comment: For forms, using a variable with an html string instead of the html string itself in `html()` **still** auto-closes the `<form>`. It is bothering me greatly